# Is there a way to be able to handle the event of google search button on the a webview?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to trigger something using the google search button is there a way to do so?

Comment: do you mean the webview page's google search button ?

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT Yeah. The button that appears on the web view once you load the Google website URL.